# React, Firebase, Firestore - Display all data

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I made a [little video](https://streamable.com/be6vvt) to make it a little clearer.

You can see that the id system with Redux is working fine (watch the console.log) and that the document exists in Firestore. But, when I put the doc (frontId), **nothing is displayed**.

All my code :

```js
    const frontId  = useSelector(selectFrontId);
    const [frontmessage] = useCollection( 
 db
.collection("front-message")
.doc(frontId)      
      );
      if (currentUser) {
        return (
          <div>
            <h1> Repondre à sa question </h1>
            {frontmessage?.docs.map((doc) => {
         const { title, message, photoURL, name} = doc.data()
        
       return (            
<>
<div>
   <p>  {title} </p>
</div>
</>

  );
})}
```

DB structure :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this code:

```
{frontmessage?.docs.map((doc) => {
```

This code assumes that `frontmessage` is a list of documents (or a `QuerySnapshot`), but your code actually only loads a single document here:

```
db
.collection("front-message")
.doc(frontId)
```

Instead of `useCollection`, you'll want to use the `useDocument` hook

```
const [doc] = useDocument(db.collection("front-message").doc(frontId));
if (currentUser) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> Repondre à sa question </h1>
      <>
        <div>
           <p>  {doc.data().title} </p>
        </div>
      </>
  );
}
```

Also see the full [example of `usseDocument](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/tree/master/firestore#full-example-1) in the` react-firebase-hooks` repo.

Comment: I changed the useCollection to useDocument, and it displayed the error `"Function CollectionReference.doc () cannot be called with an empty path."`

Comment: Did you search for that error message already? My guess is that `frontId` doesn't have a value.